# How to run JavaFX in Android Studio and make ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-studio, javafx, javafxports

I have an interface with javafx.scene.image.Image class. I must implement this and create ImageView. So, how to add JavaFx into my Android Studio Project and how to do ImageView or other Image element in my activity?

User.java

```
import javafx.scene.image.Image;

    public interface User
    {
        String getName();
        int getId();
        Image getIcon();
    }
```

Comment: @fabian Yes, you can... See the Kokos project [here](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src).

Comment: @fabian Can I convert javafx.scene.image.Image to ImageView than?

Comment: @JoséPereda cool, but can I convert javafx.scene.image to ImageView. In example, that you just sent, no information about ImageView

Comment: In that sample you see how you can add a JavaFX node to an Android fragment. By `ImageView`, are you referring to the Android's ImageView? Note that a JavaFX image has to be displayed in a _JavaFX_ `ImageView` node.

Comment: @JoséPereda Yep, Android's ImageView. I understood this code. But how can I add javaFX to my project? I've added org.javafxports:jfxmobile-plugin: dependency but User.class still dont see javaFX

Comment: First, ask yourself if you really need JavaFX in your Android project, just to deal with a JavaFX image, that is being generated from a local or remote resource. Probably you don't need that Image after all, and you can use a proper Android image?

Comment: @JoséPereda it's a test task for the vacancy. I would be glad if I did not have to use it, really)

Comment: The problem using JavaFX is that you'll need a full Scene/Stage just do display an ImageView... It can be done, for sure, but it seems overkilling. As Fabian commented, it makes sense running a full JavaFX project on Android (and iOS), but it is not very common to run a full Android project with a JavaFX fragment.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Based on [JavaFXPorts](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/) and the Kokos [sample](https://bitbucket.org/javafxports/samples/src), you can add JavaFX to an Android project created with Android Studio, and you will be able to run a JavaFX scene inside an Android fragment.

Note that JavaFXPorts is initially intended to run full JavaFX projects on Android and iOS, using plain Java, without native code. Doing it the other way around is possible, but it is not the best approach.

Anyway, these are the required steps to create a JavaFX scene with a JavaFX `ImageView` to hold a JavaFX `Image`.

**1. Create a simple project on Android Studio**

Select a Basic Activity template, and select the use of a fragment.

[image: Add a fragment]

**2. Modify the build gradle files**

*build.gradle* (top level project)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'me.tatarka:gradle-retrolambda:3.5.0'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.2.3'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

*build.gradle* (module: app)

In this file we'll include `dalvik-sdk`, the JavaFXPorts dependency for Android. If you use the Gluon plugin for your Java IDE to create mobile projects with the jfxmobile plugin, you can find it installed in:

```
~/.gradle/caches/modules-2/files-2.1/org.javafxports/dalvik-sdk/8.60.10/e...a/unpacked/dalvik-sdk
```

Else, it can be downloaded from [here](http://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/javafxports/get/). Extract it to a given path, let's say `$dalvikPath`.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 26
    buildToolsVersion "26.0.3"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "gluonhq.com.myfragment"
        minSdkVersion 25
        targetSdkVersion 26
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    dexOptions {
        preDexLibraries = false
        additionalParameters=['--core-library']
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    sourceSets {
        main {
            jniLibs.srcDir file("$dalvikPath/rt/lib")
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
        }
    }
    lintOptions {
        abortOnError false
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: '$dalvikPath/rt/lib/ext')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:26.0.0-alpha1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**3. Create a class that extends `FXFragment`**

In `MainActivity.java`:

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends FXFragment {

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
        String fxapp = "your.package.myfragment.MainFX";
        this.setName(fxapp);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }
}
```

and call it from `onCreate`:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {
        getFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(R.id.container, new PlaceholderFragment())
                .commit();
    }
    ...
}
```

Note that `android:id="@+id/container"` is required in `activity_main.xml`.

**4. Final step: create the JavaFX class**

Make sure the package name is `your.package.myfragment`.

*MainFX.java*

```
public class MainFX extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {

        final ImageView imageView = new ImageView();
        imageView.setImage(new Image("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/c/cc/JavaFX_Logo.png"));
        imageView.setPreserveRatio(true);

        Screen primaryScreen = Screen.getPrimary();
        Rectangle2D visualBounds = primaryScreen.getVisualBounds();
        double width = visualBounds.getWidth();
        double height = visualBounds.getHeight();

        StackPane stackPane = new StackPane(imageView);
        Scene scene = new Scene(stackPane, width, height);

        imageView.fitWidthProperty().bind(scene.widthProperty().subtract(20));
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

}
```

Note that this is a pure JavaFX Application class, and that you need to set the stage size base on the screen bounds.

**Deploy and run the app**

[image]

Note that you will have JavaFX running in an Android view, but you still have other Android components on different views on top of it, depending on your layout.