# How to re-code JavaFX application using Android UI classes?

Tags: android, javafx, recode

**JavaFX** Application classes are needed to **re-code using Android UI classes**. I need the alternative Android classes of the following JavaFX classes.

**For instance:** 
javafx.scene.layout.Pane; javafx.scene.shape.Line;javafx.scene.shape.Polygon;

You can check the original code here: https://github.com/piotrdzwiniel/Contour2DPlot by Piotr Dzwiniel.
I want to use some classes of the project in my android application. Thank you some much in advance.

I have already tried with **javafxports** and **Gluon Plugin** to merge two projects. I have some problems with **reading/writing** file in Android Internal Storage. So, I think it is not the best option.

Comment: Countor2DPlot should run fine on mobile (Android/iOS) using JavaFXPorts, as it just uses JavaFX. File problems can be easily addressed with Charm Down Storage service, maybe you can post them? Anyway, you can run JavaFX code on Android projects (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238603/how-to-run-javafx-in-android-studio-and-make-imageview/49246070#49246070)).

Comment: I am using Android Studio. So, How to add Charm Down Storage into the gradle of Android Studio project?

Comment: As I mentioned in my previous comment: you can do a Java project with JavaFXPorts/Gluon Mobile and Charm Down to manage the storage issue (and other native services). Or you can do an Android project and use JavaFX on it (see link I posted), then you don't need Down, you would use Android for that.

Comment: I did exactly the same as your post. I got errors when I try to read or write a file in Android storage from MainFX.class. Is there any specific function to read/write Android resources in JavaFX class?

Comment: Why don't you post a question with your issue? Use the tags `javafxports` or `gluon-mobile`.