# Android studio error: javaFXPlugin has been compiled with a more recent version

Tags: java, android-studio, javafx

I'm using the latest version of Android studio for Windows 10:

> Android Studio 4.0 Build #AI-193.6911.18.40.6514223, built on May 20, 2020

java - version in C:\Program Files\Android\android-studio-4\jre gives

> openjdk version "1.8.0_242-release" OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build
>   1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01) OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.242-b01, mixed mode)

I'm trying to install the Medusa gauge library by Hans Solo which uses the org.openjfx.javafxplugin and I'm getting the following error:

> Cause: org/openjfx/gradle/JavaFXPlugin has been compiled by a more
>   recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this
>   version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to
>   52.0

There are similar questions but I haven't found any answers that apply to Android studio. 
Is it possible to upgrade only the Android studio jdk and will this solve the problem or do I need to upgrade my Windows Java installation?

What version of Java exactly do I need to download? Or is there any other way to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: What is the purpose? An Android app? If that's the case you can't simply add JavaFX to an Android regular project (it doesn't matter if Java 1.8 or 11+). But there are ways to make your Java/JavaFX project run on Android, see for instance https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples.

Comment: The purpose is to be able to use the the JavaFX Medusa gauge library in my android app. Please go to: [https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa](https://github.com/HanSolo/Medusa). Medusas requires org.openjfx.javafxplugin. Hope that explains it better

Comment: As I said, you can't simply add JavaFX to an Android regular project. This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238603/how-to-run-javafx-in-android-studio-and-make-imageview) shows how you could add JavaFX 1.8 code to an Android app (might be outdated), The link https://github.com/gluonhq/client-samples I mentioned above allows you to create a pure Java/JavaFX app that runs on Android.