# How to add javafx classes in an android project with Android Native classes in Android Studio?(Android Native Feature/views + some javafx class/views)

Tags: android, android-studio, javafx, gluon-mobile, javafxports

Hey guys I have read almost all of the questions & answers on how to use jfxmobile, or Gluon to wrap a javafx project with gradle and to run them also on an android device. Also I know that one could use Intellij IDEA for instance have a project that is based on javafx and also handle some android classes/methods using FXActivity.getInstance(). But I have an android app in android studio with many android native code, and now I want to add some other code that relates to my application but is in javafx and I want to add them as a separate feature on my android application (not a sepparate app per say); just add them in addition to other features that were developed before using android native code in android studio. The question that I have is that how could I join those javafx apps to as a different feature in my application? I have seen Kokos sample for javafxports, but there are some issues with the Android Manifest File for now and I can't run it also it is a project of almost 5 years ago and I am not sure if the same procedures apply today with many updates. I just want to know how hard it is to do as I wish (and mentioned above)? and is it doable or there might be many issues on the way and I am better off to code for about three months of worth development with android libraries? *Time is really important in this project.

Comment: This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246070/3956070) is the last "working" version of Kokos I know of. As you already mentioned, pretty old and using JavaFXPorts which is EOL. The new [GluonFX](https://docs.gluonhq.com/#platforms_android) plugin actually creates a new pure Android project and somehow injects a JavaFX view

Comment: I suggest you give it a try, build [HelloGluon](https://github.com/gluonhq/gluon-samples/tree/master/HelloGluon) for Android and then see how you can modify the `MainActivity` that is created under `target/gluonfx/aarch64-android/gvm/android_project/app/src/main/java`, which is the one responsible for loading the JavaFX code (AOT compiled with GraalVM).

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion @JoséPereda . This way, an android project would be built that could be imported into Android Studio and add other Android Classes and features to the app? (and not create the apk as a whole separate android application which modification would be challenging to do?)

Comment: Yes, you can open it with Android Studio, and you can add Android code. Modifying the communication with the JavaFX views is not straightforward though.