# Problem adding JavaFX to Android Studio project with gradle

Tags: android-studio, gradle, javafx, libgdx

I just installed Android Studio yesterday (latest versions of all tools) and am new to gradle syntax.

My goal is to start with creating a proof of concept desktop target and make an app using GDX and javaFX.
The code below generates an error:

> error: package javafx.application does not exist   import
> javafx.application.Application;

Without the 3 javaFX imports the app runs fine.  Note: The code does not even use javaFX yet.  It is just getting hung up on the imports.  The javaFX dependencies show up in the gradle side pane.  Build-gradle was generated by libGDX. References to javaFX were added by me.

Any help would be welcomed!

Code:

```
package com.badlogic.mygame;

//import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3Application;
//import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl3.Lwjgl3ApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplication;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglApplicationConfiguration;
import com.badlogic.mygame.MyGame;

// Please note that on macOS your application needs to be started with the -XstartOnFirstThread JVM argument

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import java.awt.event.*;

// PROBLEM STARTS HERE
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.BitmapFont;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.backends.lwjgl.LwjglAWTCanvas;
// import com.badlogic.gdx.tests.MusicTest;
// import com.badlogic.gdx.tests.UITest;

// Demonstrates how to use LwjglAWTCanvas to have multiple GL widgets in a Swing application.
public class DesktopLauncher extends JFrame {
    LwjglAWTCanvas canvas1;
    LwjglAWTCanvas canvas2;
    LwjglAWTCanvas canvas3;

    public  DesktopLauncher () {
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);

        Container container = getContentPane();
        MyGame first = new MyGame();
        canvas1 = new LwjglAWTCanvas(first);
        canvas2 = new LwjglAWTCanvas(new MyGame(), canvas1);
        canvas3 = new LwjglAWTCanvas(new MyGame(), canvas1);

        canvas1.getCanvas().setSize(200, 480);
        canvas2.getCanvas().setSize(200, 480);
        canvas3.getCanvas().setSize(200, 480);

        container.add(canvas1.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.LINE_START);
        container.add(canvas2.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
        //container.add(canvas3.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        // button
        JButton myButton = new JButton("My Button");
        myButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e){
                System.out.println("clicked");
                first.setRed();
            }
        });

        container.add(myButton, BorderLayout.LINE_END);

        pack();
        setVisible(true);
        setSize(800, 480);
    }

    class WindowCreator extends ApplicationAdapter {
        SpriteBatch batch;
        BitmapFont font;

        @Override
        public void create () {
            batch = new SpriteBatch();
            font = new BitmapFont();
        }

        @Override
        public void dispose () {
            font.dispose();
            batch.dispose();
        }

        @Override
        public void render () {
            Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            batch.begin();
            font.draw(batch, "Click to create a new window", 10, 100);
            batch.end();

            if (Gdx.input.justTouched()) {
                //createWindow();
            }
        }

        private void createWindow () {
            JFrame window = new JFrame();
            /*
            LwjglAWTCanvas canvas = new LwjglAWTCanvas(new UITest(), canvas1);
            window.getContentPane().add(canvas.getCanvas(), BorderLayout.CENTER);
            window.pack();
            window.setVisible(true);
            window.setSize(200, 200);
             */
        }
    }

    public static void main (String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run () {
                 new DesktopLauncher();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void dispose () {
        canvas3.stop();
        canvas2.stop();
        canvas1.stop();

        super.dispose();
    }
}
```

Gradle:

```
    buildscript {

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        google()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'org.wisepersist:gwt-gradle-plugin:1.1.16'
        classpath 'org.gretty:gretty:3.0.7'
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.3'
        classpath 'com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-gradle-plugin:2.3.15'
        //classpath 'org.openjfx:javafx-plugin:0.0.12'
    }
}

plugins {
    id 'application'
    id 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin' version '0.0.9'
}

javafx {
    version = "15.0.1"
    modules = [ 'javafx.controls' ]
}

// apply plugin: 'java'
// apply plugin: 'jacoco'
// apply plugin: 'application'

allprojects {
    apply plugin: "eclipse"

    version = '1.0'
    ext {
        appName = "my-game"
        gdxVersion = '1.10.0'
        roboVMVersion = '2.3.15'
        box2DLightsVersion = '1.5'
        ashleyVersion = '1.7.4'
        aiVersion = '1.8.2'
        gdxControllersVersion = '2.2.1'
    }

    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()
        google()
        gradlePluginPortal()
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/snapshots/" }
        maven { url "https://oss.sonatype.org/content/repositories/releases/" }
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
    }
}

project(":desktop") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    //apply plugin: 'org.openjfx.javafxplugin'

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        // api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl3:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-lwjgl:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-desktop"
        //api "org.openjfx:javafx-graphics:17.0.1"
        implementation 'org.controlsfx:controlsfx:9.0.0'
    }
}

project(":android") {
    apply plugin: "com.android.application"

    configurations { natives }

    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-android:$gdxVersion"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-armeabi-v7a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-arm64-v8a"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86"
        natives "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-x86_64"
        
    }
}

project(":ios") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "robovm"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-rt:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.mobidevelop.robovm:robovm-cocoatouch:$roboVMVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-robovm:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-platform:$gdxVersion:natives-ios"
        
    }
}

project(":html") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"
    apply plugin: "gwt"
    apply plugin: "war"
    apply plugin: "org.gretty"


    dependencies {
        implementation project(":core")
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion:sources"
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx-backend-gwt:$gdxVersion:sources"
        
    }
}

project(":core") {
    apply plugin: "java-library"


    dependencies {
        api "com.badlogicgames.gdx:gdx:$gdxVersion"
        
    }
}
```

Comment: This is ambitious, you are mixing html, gwt, gdx, robovm, controlsfx, javafx, awt and swing to build a desktop app using a mobile targeted ide you just downloaded integrating with a build tool that you have never used before. Any number of things could go wrong and probably already has.

Comment: I advise a standard idea install with a [new JavaFX project](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/javafx.html).  When that works, learn JavaFX.  Then investigate [gluon mobile](https://gluonhq.com/products/mobile/) and learn that.  Only after you have done that, and deployed a few mobile JavaFX apps to your phone, investigate trying to get something like gdx working within a JavaFX app on a mobile device.

Comment: If you put your application adapter class in your desktop module, then your app cannot be multiplatform. You might as well delete those other modules: iOS, html, android, and core. I recommend avoiding doing that, just in case you decide later you want to support another platform. But you can delete the modules you don't want to support yet, keeping just `core` and `desktop`. But why are you using Android Studio if this app is for JavaFX?

Comment: If I understand the implication, the IDE choice somehow adds complexity when targeting the desktop that others (Eclipse, netbeans) would not.   To be clear,  this is a proof of concept to see if libGDX and javaFX can work together.  I don't care about the other targets or which IDE is used.  The other targets were added by the libGDX project creator and android studio was the recommended IDE.  I guess I will start with javaFX in a different IDE.  Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: As an aside, can Android Studio not generate stock Java apps?  Eg: Does it always layer the code on the Android SDK potentially causing conflicts that would not be seen in other IDEs?

Comment: I have never used Android Studio. I don't know if Android Studio can be used to build "stock" Java applications. I know that IntelliJ Idea and other IDEs can be used that way. After answering thousands of JavaFX questions, this is the first time that I have seen Android Studio and JavaFX mentioned within the same sentence. There have been other questions about the combo, [nine (including yours)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javafx+android-studio).

Comment: Three questions are answered, two answers say to use a different IDE.  [Only one answer is actually about using the two together](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49246070/1155209) and that documents an obsolete configuration which may not function for later JavaFX versions.  JavaFX 11 deployments are quite different from pre JavaFX 11 deployments due to the removal of JavaFX from the Oracle JDK and the move to provide it as a set of modules.

Comment: If you're not targeting Android, IntelliJ IDEA is the easiest IDE for working in libGDX. Android Studio would be fine, but it will have a number of superfluous features if you're not targeting Android.