# How to include javafx ports into Android Studio from path

Tags: android-studio, javafx, port

There are 3 important folders in android plugin(android-tools,lib,rt).Do We need to add all of them to our Android Studio project? And how to setup on build.gradle and MainActivity? I downloaded the javafx ports Android plugin(dalvik-sdk) and copied the files from "rt" folder to my projects libs folder. After that tried to setup my build.gradle as shown here:
[How to run JavaFX in Android Studio and make ImageView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49238603/how-to-run-javafx-in-android-studio-and-make-imageview)
but it end up with black screen.I debug with physical device(Samsung Galaxy S5,Android version 6.0.1).

Tried to debug with virtual device Pixel Api_23.But it ended another error: "/data/app/com.example.fx_appfragment-2/lib/x86_64/libactivity.so" has unexpected e_machine

Comment: Why are you using the very old JavaFXPorts plugin (for Java 1.8), and not the new GluonFX plugin? It will create a full grade project that you can open from Android Studio. What do you want to accomplish?

Comment: I have a JavaFX project made with jdk8 and I want to convert it into Android Studio Project. I am not aware of the GluonFX plugins and how to use them.

Comment: You mean that you want to convert it to an Android project, that can be edited from Android Studio? With the [GluonFX](https://docs.gluonhq.com) plugin you can build an deploy apk to an Android device, but you still have a Java/JavaFX project nonetheless (that requires a Java IDE).

Comment: Yes, my main purpose is to deploy Android apk from my javafx project. I will read the documentation step by step. Thank you very much!

Comment: I started trying with intellij ide.I downloaded the plugin and Created new project. But the compiling ended with error:
Cannot resolve com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:pom:6.1.0 failed to transfer from 
https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases during a previous attempt. This failure was cached in the local repository and resolution is not reattempted until the update interval of Gluon has elapsed or updates are forced. 
Original error: Could not transfer artifact com.gluonhq:charm-glisten:pom:6.1.0 from/to Gluon (https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases):

Comment: Is it Gluon IDE plugin 2.8.6? [Glisten 6.1.0](https://nexus.gluonhq.com/nexus/content/repositories/releases/com/gluonhq/charm-glisten/6.1.0/) should be reachable. Anyway, you can try to update the pom with Glisten 6.2.2 and GluonFX plugin 1.0.16?